# Environment Specific Eureka properties is not loading

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-profiles

I have created a Eureka Client and Server project using spring Cloud 1.5.17 version. Both the project is working fine but the issue is that based on environment I want certain eureka properties to be loaded at run-time for the client project. For that what I have done is that I have created environment specific property file for eureka like as shown below.

[image]

I have tried all the below three properties in application.yml but none of them seems not picking the **eureka-client-test.properties** properties

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: test

eureka:
  instance:
    environment: test

eureka:
  instance:
    environment:
      active-profiles:
      - test
```

Can anyone please help me on this

Full source code is committed and is available under the below bitbucket repository

[https://bitbucket.org/resh32/eureka](https://bitbucket.org/resh32/eureka/src/master/)

Comment: eureka server via spring cloud does not recognize those files.

Comment: @spencergibb Then how can we do this.... any other way

Comment: Did my provided solution resolve you query ? Were you able to achieve the desired result ? Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). As the asker, you have a special privilege: you may accept the answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override this property `eureka.client.props` with your property file name without `.properties` suffix.
So lets say you specify your spring active env using `spring.profiles.active` & then in corresponding `application-env.properties` file you can set `eureka.client.props` to `eureka-client-env`.